# Centering CSS menu

Tags: css, menu

I have found a CSS menu that I wanted to implement to my webpage. The menu can be seen here:

http://apycom.com/menus/4-red.html

The problem is, that I am not an expert on CSS, but I would like to do some changes, but unfortunately no matter what I tried it didnt do what I needed.

So basically, the CSS is here:
http://apycom.com/ssc-data/themes/default/styles/menu.css

Now what I would like is to have the exact same menu, but have it centered on a page. I tried various things, but it never worked.
And also, if it would be possible to have it stretched to 100% of the screen. I also tried that but unsuccesfully.

Comment: Can you show some code, preferably some HTML?

Comment: Show us the HTML please.

Comment: The HTML is not really important, is just a div with ul and li. I think what needs to be changed is the CSS given in the link. You can look at the source code in the page to see the actual HTML, but asi I said, that is not where the changes are necessary.

Comment: I tried changing the CSS, but it is always on the left, never centered. I want the entire menu to be in the center and possibly stretched to 100% of the screen. I tried setting width to 100%, but it didnt work.

Comment: The idea behind this website is that you show your problem and that usually includes showing your code in the question, not via a link. And the HTML is going to help us help you. So the HTML IS important (only CSS is not going to work as we can not see a result).

Comment: @user2370078 Can you make a JSFiddle of the code?

Comment: here it is: http://brzezina.cz/meteo/my/menutest.htm

Comment: I will try, just a second

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/98tW6/10/

Answer (score 0):

Look Man See this: http://cdpn.io/jbhkD . 
The only thing you've to do is first specify a width to the menu like I've used in my example : `width : 500px;` and then set the margin as I've put in there `margin : 0 auto;` to make the menu in the center of the page.

The menu don't have the easing effect because you've to buy the full version of the menu, or a link of the apycom website will appear on the menu.

I've just focused on the centering of the menu.
Hope I've Helped You ^_^